# How to deploy in AWS using a Docker compose File

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy a docker file in AWS, I've read about it and I can do it through ECS or Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm not sure which one is the best.

this is my docker-compose file (this is the only file in the project):

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "6666:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        managementApiSecret: ${PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET}
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: ${DB_HOST}
            database: ${DB_DB}
            schema: public
            user: ${DB_USER}
            password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            rawAccess: true
            port: '5432'
            migrations: true
            connectionLimit: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in Elastic Beanstalk you need provide a Dockerfile and you can forget about the infrastructure, the EB care about everything. Already in ECS you need build infrastructure before deploy the Docker fiile. So, the choice depends of effort that you want to spend on the infrastructure.

Comment: I tried to do it using Elastic Beanstalk but I didn't know how to upload my docker-compose file, do you have any idea?

Comment: @HugoLicon You can use ECR to upload your docker image. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-basics.html

Comment: Following the tutorial: http://blog.digitopia.com/elastic-beanstalk-docker-deployment/